# latex how to control the symbol of \IEEEauthorrefmark

Tags: formatting, affiliation

I want to change the symbol for the affiliation. I want to use `#` instead of `*` or even use numbers instead of symbols. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{AuthorA \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, AuthorB \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}AffA
                    \\\{a.b $|$ c.d\}@abc.com \\
                  \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}AffB
                  \\a.b@abc.com
                }
}%end author

% make the title area
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the definition used by the class with the `transmag` option:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize #1}}%
}


\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\author{
  \IEEEauthorblockN{%
    AuthorA\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\,\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
    AuthorB\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}
  }
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}AffA\\\{a.b $|$ c.d\}@abc.com \\
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}AffB\\a.b@abc.com
  }
}%end author

% make the title area
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't leave a space between the name and `\IEEEauthorrefmark`.

[image]