# The thank star disappears from author

Tags: author

I want to add a corresponding author with \thanks，but the star in the upper left corner of the author disappeared. How can I add the star?

The follow is my latex code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\title{A Good Name is the Half of a Good article}
\author[1]{Author B}
\author[2]{Author C \thanks{* is the corresponding author.}}

\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}


\renewcommand*{\Affilfont}{\small\it} 
\renewcommand\Authands{ and } 
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Hello, Hello 
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

This is the performance .Author C  has only numbers marked, no stars.How can I get a star right upper the author C. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that replicates the output... your current code snippet(s) doesn't do that. It should include a `\begin{document}`...`\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is obsolete and deprecated. Don't use it. Instead, use either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: Your minimal example doesn't compile, throwing errors about unknown commands (like `\affil`, `\Affilfont` and `\Authands`. So I'm not sure how you're achieving the output you're showing... can you fix your minimal example so it replicates the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the MWE solves your problem.

As you are using the `conference` mode of the `IEEEtran` class, I have used the `\IEEEauthorblockN{}` and `\IEEEauthorblockA{}` commands to make it easier to format the author names and affiliations correctly.

To change the author affiliation symbols into numbers, I have used code snippets from [an answer of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380683/219947).

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Changes author affiliation symbols into numbers
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmarkNum}[1]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize #1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\title{A Good Name is the Half of a Good article}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{%
    Author A\IEEEauthorrefmarkNum{1}, Author B\IEEEauthorrefmarkNum{1}, Author C\IEEEauthorrefmarkNum{2}\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\thanks{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}is the corresponding author.}
    }
    \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University\\
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University
    }
} % end author
    
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    Author footnote
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

First Page:

[image: First page]

Comment: Thanks, You help a lot